# Importing model to Gazebo 11 all links spawned at origin

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I have made a custom gazebo model and was able to rig up all the links, joints and plugins in the model editor and save the model. However, every time I restart gazebo and insert my saved model, all the links would be spawned at the origin and not at the correct respective poses defined in the sdf file. (See image below).

[image: image description]

Once I edit model, all the links would move to the correct positions but I will need to save the model again and exit model editor for the links to stay in the right position. If I do not save the model before exiting model editor, the links would stay at the origin after exiting model editor. I am using Gazebo Classic 11 on Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried changing the sdf versions, and also tried using the relative_to function for the poses of the links, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29116/importing-model-to-gazebo-11-all-links-spawned-at-origin/) by [airoverr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/184396/airoverr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I assume the model is not static. If you start the world in pause mode, or add the model while the world is paused, are the links in the model in the correct poses? Then when played, all the links go to the origin? If yes, that may mean your physics parameters in the model is not correct, and causing some `inf` or `NaN` in one of the links' poses. This can be caused by zero mass or inertia, for example, but there can be more possibilities.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2023-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0